# Any reason for first print NL, then text, then manually flush compared to print text and NL?

Tags: c, file-io, output

I recently needed to debug some really old legacy code, mainly designed for some microcontroller.

In this code, all printf-calls follow the same convention:

```
fprintf(outfile, "\r\nFormat %d", someinteger);
fflush(outfile);
```

You can see, the code first prints a NL (and a CR, code was written by a Win98-veteran), then the text. At the end he manually flushes the file (sometimes `stdout` sometimes a normal `FILE*`).
In my knowledge this is laborious since printing `\n` already flushes the handle, so the following code would be sufficient.

```
fprintf(outfile, "Format %d\r\n", someinteger);
```

Is there any reason to chose the first snippet for printing text and manually flushing the handle compared to the second snippet where the flush is implied by `\n`?

Comment: Some people don't like the last character in their text files being a newline. They prefer to define lines as "the characters between newlines, excluding the newlines if present". The Unix philosophy is that a line includes the trailing newline, even for the last line in a text file. `echo -ne "a\nb" | wc -l` reports 1 line.

Comment: @pmg that sounds reasonable, however, by looking at the rest of the code (many empty lines printed for readability, counting wont be the case. However then it could be out of habit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an old dinosaur fed with Fortran IV, K&R C and Unix V7 milk, I can understand this code.

The initial `\r\n` ensures that whatever the console mode, the cursor will be positionned at the beginning of a line. As a serial line consoles veteran, I often saw a console left in raw mode because a full screen (read curses...) program crashed and failed to restore the cooked mode. And we have to type `stty sane ^J` (yes <kbd>Ctrl + J</kbd> and not <kbd>Return</kbd> which only sended a useless `^M`) to recover it.

The `fflush` after a `\n` still makes sense if the output can be redirected to a file or pipe. Because the automatic flush after a `\n` only occur (in Unix/Linux) when output directly goes to a terminal, and not when it goes to a file or pipe. So I would say that this code assumes to be possibly used in a rather hostile environment and just does its best to ensure that the text will be readable.

Comment: When I think of the purpose of the code and where it came from, this makes perfect sense and is understandable! Im curious if some other folks may have other ideas so I really would like to postpone to accept the answer for a couple of hours if this is OK for you.